# How is a categoryID added to an Issue?

Tags: workfront-api

I am using a C# example provided by Workfront to interact with the Api.
*https://developers.workfront.com/api-docs/code-samples/*

I want to be able to update an Issue with a new categoryID or add the value when creating the Issue.

I'd also like to assign a value to one of the parameters in the category.

Answer (score 0):

had same problem

this request works for me

```
> PUT https://{domain}/attask/api/v5.0/category/{categoryId}/assignCategory?objID={taskId}&objCode=TASK&categoryID={categoryId}
> Accept: application/json
> Content-Type: text/plain
```

notice to send body as empty plain text (it was my problem)